# HTML5 video.currentTime not being set properly

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have an HTML5 webpage example

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function log(msg) { console.log(msg); }

$(document).ready(function() {
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.load();
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(){
  video.currentTime = 95.061728395;
});
});
</script>
<body>
<video id="video" preload="none" height="360" width="640">
<source src="news.mp4">
  Your browser does not support this video.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

that manually sets the currentTime property of a video tag, however it is seeking to a different frame than what I get using OpenCV/mplayer and seeking to the same time.

Using javascript, I seek to the video at a valid time, and I am given a frame that is usually 2 frames before the frame that it should be. I am using

`video.currentTime = 95.061728`

in the browser and

`echo -n p | mplayer -ss 95.061728395 static/news.mp4`

as a command that replicates what the frame should be.  The OpenCV code matches what the mplayer frame seeks to.

From mplayer, the video format is:

```
Playing static/news.mp4.  
libavformat version 53.21.1 (external)  
Mismatching header version 53.19.0  
libavformat file format detected.  
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0  
[lavf] stream 1: audio (aac), -aid 0, -alang und  
VIDEO:  [H264]  640x360  24bpp  29.970 fps  500.4 kbps (61.1 kbyte/s)  
Clip info:  
 major_brand: mp42  
 minor_version: 0  
 compatible_brands: isommp42  
 creation_time: 2011-09-27 14:41:05  
Load subtitles in static  
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family  
libavcodec version 53.35.0 (external)  
Mismatching header version 53.32.2  
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpe`enter code here`g H.264)  
Opening audio decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg/libavcodec audio decoders  
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 96.0 kbit/6.80% (ratio: 12001->176400)  
Selected audio codec: [ffaac] afm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg AAC (MPEG-2/MPEG-4 Audio))  
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)  
Starting playback...  
Unsupported PixelFormat 61  
Unsupported PixelFormat 53  
Unsupported PixelFormat 81  
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.  
VO: [vdpau] 640x360 => 640x360 Planar YV12
```

I am using Chrome Version 30.0.1599.114 as a browser on Linux g6 3.2.0-54-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there a ban system in place on SO?

Comment: Dang, now I look like the jerk after he deleted all the comments he made. Sorry zanman, have you encoded this video using the recommended settings for Web? Seems like something that could be caused by b-frame settings or some other goofy property therein.

Comment: No problem! I will check those setting again for sure and post them, I was using avconv to convert it from avi to mp4

Comment: What's the 'player' in use ? Like, can you change your browser default video player and test further? Test with Totem or VLC or .. else.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18105160/video-currenttime-doesnt-want-to-be-set, useless-related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340164/changing-src-and-currenttime-doesnt-work-together, verry-related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839663/issues-with-html5-video-currenttime-property

Comment: I'm using whatever the standard HTML5 player is for chrome, and I'm using mplayer to test it on the system. I'll look into the time ranges issue again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having a code to test with this answer will be theorizing a possible cause -

As you see the video FPS is 29.97. My guess is that the Chrome browser (which do use ffmpeg for mp4 decoding) simply rounds the FPS to 30 FPS. One reason for can be that the updates are synced to the monitors refresh rate typically at 60 Hz. This means to get a "clean" frame the video frame rate runs at 30 FPS rather than 29.97 which is used for analog NTSC (just my theory on how the browser handles this anyways).

This will give you:

```
@30.00 FPS frame 2852
@29.97 FPS frame 2849
```

which corresponds about to the difference you experience (3 frames).

To compensate for this you can recalculate your time-base this way:

```
newTime = oldTime / 30 * 29.97;
```

This will adjust the time to be:

```
95.061728395 / 30 * 29.97 = 94.96666666660501
```

If we use this time instead (for `currentTime`) with 30 FPS we will get:

```
94.96666666660501 * 30 => frame 2849
```

as if it was running with 29.97 FPS.

Comment: This was actually giving me the frame that is 2 frames in the wrong direction, but doing 95.061728395 / 29.97 * 30 gave me the correct frame.  I'm yet to fully implement this solution, but I believe it is correct.  I cannot thank you enough, this was such a good idea to try!

Comment: I have the same issue; however multiplying a constant did not worked for me. My video FPS is 29.92. I'm using OpenCV to get the frame millisecond. My tries showed that shift is not linear. When I use a constant that corrects frames close to the beginning, it does not work on the times close to the end of the video and vice versa.